# Ajax Jquery Post to MVC action keeps on in-definitively (many times)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I am doing a test, well, try to make the skeleton code to post and answer AJAX calls from a MVC view to my controller's action vice-versa and my POST is going at the right place and the answer data seems to work as well but it KEEPS ON POSTING in-definitively back to my action. Im no PRO with JQuery and I am trying to figure out what is missing in my client side script. I tried to use e.preventdefault but I doubt this is the right way to handle this issue. Here is my code:

My post/MVC action will return this (like i said its a test/skeleton):

```
                return Json(new
                {
                    Result = true,
                    Message = "Call Successfull."
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This is the result script onSuccess

```
    function OfferAjaxOnSuccess(data) {

        if (!data.Result) {
            alert(data.Message); // my own MessageBox
            return;
        } else if (data.Result == true) {
            alert(data.Message); // my own MessageBox
        }

    };
```

Finally the Ajax form post instructions:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendOffer", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "OfferAjaxOnSuccess" }))
            {
```

As I said, my problem is that the alert(...); inside onsuccess method and post popup will indefinitively!? Why? and what is missing or wrong in my code/script? I tried already to figure out what is on your FAQ but can't seem to see what is missing or wrong...

Thank you in advance for advice and help :)

Mart

Comment: Where do you assign the variable `e` that you use in `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Actually, these two you can REMOVE from the code e.preventDefault(); // prevent this submit
        $(this).submit(false); // prevent future submits

Comment: I just want 1. Figure out WHY it keeps on posting. 2. I want only one post and return. Back and forth seems to be ok posting data and return data OK.

Comment: If it can help the post is triggered by this button. <button class="btn-info btn-lg btn-block active" onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('offerType').value = 2;" @dis>Send your offer</button>

Comment: @Barmar, you don't know? I did not add the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to my bundle, i added to my partialview just once to make sure it isnt called anywhere else...

Comment: I found it! My bad I guess, I put the <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> inside my PartialView... A quick test while putting the ref inside the layout prooved I was right. Now post only once! Rookie move... Thanx nway. I guess this ticket can be closed...